# Summarizing different (local) shapefiles/sources into one centralized database using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.2, layers, map-package

Using ArcMap/ArcCatalog 10.2, is there a way, to summarize a huge number of widely spread shapefiles/sources (different servers, different hard drives etc.) into one centralized database, in order to be able to transfer this database as well as a corresponding mxd-file e.g. to a notebook or another computer without internet connection?

Answer (score 2):

This is very easily done by adding each of these data sources to a map and then [Creating a map package](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//006600000403000000):

> Map packages (.mpk) make it easy to share complete map documents with
>   others. A map package contains a map document (.mxd) and the data
>   referenced by the layers it contains, packaged into one convenient,
>   portable file.

The same functionality is also available in the [Package Map (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000q5000000):

> Packages a map document and all referenced data sources to create a
>   single compressed .mpk file.